# Referencing in a simple way using AngularJS and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio, typescript

I'm using VS2015 with Gulp and I'm trying to build AngularJS with TypeScript.

In my index.html, I have a script tag to my "app.js" (the output and bundle of the TS build).

However if I want to reference my controller, and any other services - how can I avoid having to put the relevant script tags in each and every HTML file - is there a way I can just reference the app.js file and be done with it? What's the recommended approach?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

if you want to refrence only one file in html via script tag and other files just reference in other js files then you can use [requirejs](http://requirejs.org). It is a nice tool to load scripts. in production it is a good approach to concat and minify all your scripts to reduce number of requests.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve it using `experimental typescript decorators`, `requirejs` and a little of imagination.

So, in resume I wrote two decorators one called `AppStartup` and other called `DependsOn`. So at angular bootstrap I can get and register all dependencies.

I ended up with something like it:

---

TodoListController.ts

```
import {DependsOn, AppStartup, ngControllerBase} from "../infra/core";
import {taskManagerDirective} from "../directives/TaskManagerDirective";

@AppStartup({
    Name: "TodoSample"
}).Controller({
    DependsOn: [taskManagerDirective]
})
export class TodoListController extends ngControllerBase {
    public ByControllerAs: string;

    constructor() {
        super(arguments);

        let $httpPromise = this.$get<ng.IHttpService>("$http");

        $httpPromise.then(function ($http) {
            $http.get('http://www.google.com').success(function (body) {
                console.info("google.com downloaded, source code: ", body);
            });
        });

        this.ByControllerAs = "This was included by controllerAs 'this'";
    }
}
```

---

rowListItemDirective.ts

```
import {DependsOn, ngDirectiveBase} from "../infra/core";
import {rowListItemDirective} from "./RowListItemDirective";

@DependsOn([rowListItemDirective])
export class taskManagerDirective extends ngDirectiveBase{
    public template: string = `
    Parent Directive
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr row-list-item-directive></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
   `;
}
```

You can see what I did below at my github repository:

https://github.com/klaygomes/angular-typescript-jasmine-seed